# Why I get the error: "there is more than one default constructor"?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, c++17, default-constructor

I get the message:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error (active) E0339 class "D" has more than one default constructor)

and:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C2668 'D::D': ambiguous call to overloaded function)

The error occurs in line marked with //(2)

if I remove line marked with //(1) the I can build my code.

```
class C {
    int i, j;

public:
    C(int x, int y) : i(x), j(y)
    {
        cout << "Konstr C" << endl;
    }
    C() : i(0), j(0)
    {
        cout << "Std-Konstr C" << endl;
    }
        ~C()
    {
        cout << "Destruktor C" << endl;
    }
};
class D : public C {
    int k, a, b;
    C c;
public:

    D():c(){ cout << "Std-Konstr D" << endl; }// (1)

    D(int x = 1) :c(x, 1), a(x), b(0), k(19)

    {
        cout << "Konstr-1 D" << endl;
    }
    D(int x, int y, int z) :C(x, y), a(1), b(2), c(x, y), k(z)
    {
        cout << "Konstr-2 D" << endl;
    }
    ~D()
    {
        cout << "Destruktor D" << endl;
    }
};
class E : public D {
    int m;
    C c;
    D b;
public:
    E(int x, int y) : c(2, 3), b(y), m(x + y)// (2)
    {
        cout << "Konstr E" << endl;
    }
    ~E()
    {
        cout << "Destruktor E" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Which constructor would be invoked at `D d{};`? (1) `D()` or (2) `D(int x = 1)`

Comment: You may find the unabbreviated error messages on the Output tab to be better quality than those presented on the Error List tab. Easier to cut and paste, too.

Comment: @VTT, now i see my mistake, Thank u!

Comment: @user4581301 That is a great tip thank u, now i can fix my problems more accurat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, `D()` is ambiguous. The compiler has no way pf knowing if you meant to call the no-arg constructor, or the `int` constructor with a default value of `1`.

One way to clear this ambiguity is to remove the default value of the `x` parameter:

```
D():c(){ cout << "Std-Konstr D" << endl; }// (1)

D(int x) :c(x, 1), a(x), b(0), k(19)
//    ^-- x=1 was removed here
{
    cout << "Konstr-1 D" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @PeteBecker Well... bollocks to it then. :)

Comment: (N.B. that's `[class.default.ctor]/1` these days)